# How to give linear gradient to a image pulled in HTML?

Tags: html, image, linear-gradients

I have an image in HTML

I want to give linear gradient to it. I know how to give linear gradient to a pic pulled in CSS. But can we do the same if we have an image pulled in HTML without giving it inline CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood correctly you can do that by adding the style attribute to the image and then add the css inside that.

Comment: Isn't that will be inline CSS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you need the following:

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg" />
  <div class="grad"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.grad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    transparent 0%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
  );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/whjptge1/

Please correct and share your fiddle if your question addresses the different problem

Comment: Your way is correct but I was thinking to avoid using div but I guess I have to go with it now as I don't have any other option. Thank you.

Comment: It is required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site like a jsfiddle.